# Display data from database using java

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to make a connection with MySQL datatbase and I'm using Tomcat v6.0. The source code in Java is this:

ConnectionManager.java

```
package admin;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class ConnectionManager {
    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;

    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String CONN_STRING =
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sondazh";

    private Connection conn = null;

    private ConnectionManager() {
    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private boolean openConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;

    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
            try {
                if (openConnection()) {
                    return conn;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

DatabaseObject.java

```
package admin;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public abstract class DatabaseObject {

    private static Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getInstance()
            .getConnection();

    public static ResultSet query(String sql) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            return rs;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());    
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static boolean update(String sql){
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            int affected = stmt.executeUpdate();

            if(affected == 0){
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int insert(String sql){
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            int affected = stmt.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            return affected;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have created getter and setter for all entities in my database 
but when I run it shows me an error:

HTTP Status 404 - type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.36

i want to display some data from User entity :

```
test.jsp

<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="admin.User"%>
<%@page import="admin.ConnectionManager"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title> test </title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
        <table>
            <%
            ResultSet rs = User.loadAll(); 
                while (rs.next()) { 
            %> 

            <tr>
               <TH>ID</TH>
               <TH>Name</TH>
               <TH>Surname</TH>
               <TH>Email</TH>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td> <%= rs.getInt(1) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(2) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(3) %> </td>
               <td> <%= rs.getString(4) %> </td>


           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

       <% 
           } 
       %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is test.jsp that i try to run but i can't get the result that i want because of error that i mentioned earlier . Tomcat is running. Is my jsp code ok?

Comment: The problem is that the URL you use in your browser does not hit your code at all.  You need another URL

Comment: Your jsp seems unreachable !!!

Comment: What URL are you hitting and where is your jsp ?

Comment: isp is placed at WEB-INF file in eclipse..and i run it and url is http://localhost:8080/Sondazh/WEB-INF/test.jsp

Comment: @Anna S :See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Directly deploying to TOMCAT]

[image: Via Eclipse]

```
  localhost:8080/Sondazh/WEB-INF/test.jsp <<--- JSP is under WEB-INF here.
```

You cannot directly access this. It is not a standard Servlet/JSP Spec. The container looks for class-files in WEB-INF and if you ask for JSP in this directory, it will return an error 404.The resources which need to be protected from Http access are placed under WEB-INF.**To directly access the JSP , keep it outside the WEB-INF .** If deployed in Tomcat , you can put the JSP under , `\apache-tomcat-version\webapps\Sondazh\test.jsp` and hit it using `localhost:8080/Sondazh/test.jsp`.

Comment: i did what you told and i just put it at java resources /src/ admin http://localhost:8080/Sondazh/WEB-INF/classes/admin/test.jsp  but the problem is still the same

Comment: for example where? because when i paste it at web file it goes automaticaly at WEB-INF

Comment: How are you deploying your app ? via Eclipse or manually copying the files to Tomcat ?

Comment: i am deploying it via eclipse

Comment: i think it works now but now have a problem with jsp  HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 19

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 19

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /test.jsp at line 19

16:   <table>
17:    <%
18:    ResultSet rs = User.loadAll(); 
19:     while (rs.next()) { 
20:     %> 
21:        
22:             <tr>

Comment: Where did you define 'User' in the JSP ?

Comment: <%@page import="admin.User"%> where User is a class that has getter and setter for the same entity in database and has a method    public static ResultSet loadAll() {
  return query("SELECT * FROM user");
 }

Comment: is while (rs.next())  or while (rs.hasnext()) ?

Comment: i solved the problem but still  HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NullPointerException
type Exception report
message java.lang.NullPointerException
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)

Answer (score 0):

404 has nothing to do with the database. The web server is unable to locate the resource identified by the URL. Your problem is with the URL or the web server configuration.

Comment: url jdbc:mysql://localhost/sondazh  its ok.. what do you mean with web server configuration ( tomcat is not ok ? )